# What do Islamic scriptures say about the fate of Israel?

Tags: future

- [Did Islam Accurately Predict the End of Israel?](https://youtu.be/13iBV6mztow)

According to the above link, the Islamic predictions of Palestinian liberation and the end of Israel are now looking accurate. However, this video doesn't say what those Islamic predictions are.

What do Islamic scriptures say about the fate of Israel?

Comment: What makes you think that israel-palestine conflict is related to religion ?